# Is there a way to group and hide tray/notification area icons in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.10, notification-area

tray icons take a lot of space. is there a solution that is similar to windows 7, where the tray icons are grouped together and hidden?

any other way to reduce the number of tray icons? one way i can think of is to make a seperate panel that auto-hides.

Comment: You could always switch to KDE. The KDE panel tray/notification thingy allows you to hide icons.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-hiding panel seems to be the one most people use. Reducing the number of tray icon is quite similar to using GTD to clean your to-do list. Just look for icons you don't really need and find a way to get rid of them.